# Properly serialize a value so it is passed to CurrentUserField() properly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I started using Django REST this week, and I am running into something I do not understand.

I building a POST that takes in the following payload:

```
{
  "requestor":"naughtron",
  "test_name":"testName",
  "workers":"2"
}
```

The value for requestor in our data model is set to CurrentUserField()

When the payload comes into the serializer

```
class TestSuiteRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    requestor = what_do_use_here?
    test_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100) 
    workers = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=True, max_length=3)
```

the following error is thrown

```
database_1  | ERROR:  null value in column "requestor" violates not-null constraint
```

because I am believe it is not being serialized properly therefore the model has no idea what to do.

I looked through the documentation and the current list of Serializer fields. Nothing seems to be helping.

I tried using a basic `serializers.CharField` but that threw an error stating `must be a "User" instance.`

Comment: Have you tried using `CurrentUserDefault` field? (like they show in the example [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault)). This way you don't even have to pass `requestor` in the payload, the serializer would get `request.user` "automagically".

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I'll give it a go.